# Custom remote validator error message

Tags: parsley.js

With a custom remote validator, how are you supposed to get rid of the error messages?

Using data-parsley-remote-validator='mycustom' on the field will give you an error in the console 'undefined async validator' unless the validator is added on DOM ready i.e not inside another function. However, if it is added on DOM ready, then parsley automatically calls it, which shouldn't happen until submit/change or whatever else you have set.

I can do something like this, but it kind of defeats the object of having parsley call the validator on change:

```
$('#signUpForm').on('submit', function() {
//add the attribute here to avoid the initial error message
  $('#exampleInputEmail1').attr('data-parsley-remote-validator', 'validateEmail');
//then add the custom validator
  $('#exampleInputEmail1').parsley()
  .addAsyncValidator('validateEmail', function (xhr) {
           if(xhr.status == '200') {
               return 200;
             }
          // return the error message if email is taken
           else if(xhr.status == '404') {
             response = '<ul class="errorlist"><li>That email has already been taken, please try another</li></ul>'
             $('#errorResponse').html(response);
            }
      }, '/api/v1/email/available', { "type": "POST", "dataType": "json", "data": data }
   );
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who came here for custom remote validator error message in Parsley.js,

You can add `data-parsley-remote-message` to the element,

```
<input type="text"  data-parsley-remote-validator="my_remote_validator" data-parsley-remote-message="Custom error message only for remote validation on this element" >
```

Tested with **Parsley.js - Version 2.3.11**

Answer (score 1):

Your asynch validator is not supposed to set an error message itself, it should simply return if the value validates or not. The error messages are added with a different API and/or specified as data attributes, check the doc.

Comment: Ok I can remove that, but I'll still have the issue with error messages in the console. The addAsyncValidator is adding and calling, rather than just adding, thats the issue. What's the proper usage? Thanks

Comment: If you use two remote validators on the same field, how do you set different messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validation message using an AsyncValidator through the function you pass to the validator

```
function (xhr) {

// if validations are good, return true or a resolved promise
  if (xhr.status == 200)
    return true;

// Return a rejected promise with the error message you want to display
return Promise.reject("Custom Validation Error")

}
```

In this way you can set a custom error message per validator and/or in according with the result of the request

Tested with **Parsley.js - Version 2.9.2**